# REST with CORS not working with WebExtension content-script

Tags: javascript, rest, cors, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a webextension in Firefox for use internally at work. The purpose of the extension is to insert relevant information from our ServiceNow instance into Nagios host/service page.

I am currently trying to insert the state of tickets into the history tab of Nagios. My script looks like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('id_historytab_table');
var table = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
var table = table[1];
var len = table.children.length

const url = "https://[domain].service-now.com/api/now/table/task?sysparm_limit=1&number="

for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    var col = table.rows[i].cells[2];
    if (col.textContent.startsWith("TKT")) {
        var tkt = col.textContent;
        //console.log(tkt);
        //console.log(url+tkt);

        var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
        invocation.open("get",url+tkt, true);
        invocation.withCredentials = true;
        invocation.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if(this.readyState == this.DONE) {
                //console.log('recieved');
                console.log(invocation.responseText);
                //console.log(JSON.parse(invocation.responseText).result[0].state);
            }
        }; 

        invocation.send();
    };
};
```

This successfully gets the ticket number from each row of the history tab and makes a GET request. I can see the requests on my ServiceNow REST log and it looks good there. However, the response is never received.

If I copy and paste the above from my `content-script.js` and put it directly into my console I am able to iterate through the rows, get the ticket numbers, and successfully receive responses from ServiceNow. So this works, but not in WebExtension for some reason. I am about at the end of my knowledge of extensions and javascript though and am not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. In order for the WebExtension to receive the response the URL needs to be under permissions in the manifest.json. Adding:

```
"permissions": [ "url" ],
```

resolved the issues and I immediately began seeing the response bodies I was expecting.